# How to make a 'for in range' random?

Tags: python

I have this small piece of code that I want to make random between certain value

```py
for i in range(1, ad.photo_counter()):
    photo_field = self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@type="file"]')[i]
    photo_field.send_keys(ad.photos[i])
```

The `ad.photo_counter()` gets the total amount of photos stored in a folder. Lets say this is 3. I then want the `send_key(ad.photos[i])` to be a random number not a straight number from 1 to 10 for example. Any idea?

Comment: to do that you need to know the length of `ad.photos` beforehand

Comment: If you only want things to happen once, a `for` loop is the wrong choice.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest for ease of read i left out that part ;) of course it is known before this is called. 

SilvioMayolo you are right! Made a grammer error: I meant that I want to have it random all the time as long as it is in the for loop ;) and not take photo 1, photo 2, photo 3 but rather want: photo 2, photo 1, photo 3 etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `random.randint(low, high)`

```py
import random

index = random.randint(0, NUM_PHOTOS) # assuming you have the number of photos in NUM_PHOTOS
```

Or you can use `random.choice(list)`

```py
import random

pickedPhoto = random.choice(ad.photos)
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert your `range(1, ad.photo_counter())` to a list, and then use [random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

```py
import random

my_values = list(range(1, 10))
random.shuffle(my_values)
print(my_values)
```

Answer (score 2):

for this you will need to `import random` and call `random.randint(inclusive,exclusive)`.

```
import random

for i in range(1, ad.photo_counter()):
                        photo_field = self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@type="file"]')[i]
                        photo_field.send_keys(ad.photos[random.randint(0,ad.photo_counter())])
```

You can see how to do random number generation in python from [this link](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-python/)

Answer (score 2):

Another way you could do this is with `random.sample` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample). This function generate a list of k values by randomly sampling from a list of values. So, in code form you could do something like the following:

```
import random

for i in random.sample(range(1, ad.photo_counter()), k = ad.photo_counter() - 1):
    photo_field = self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@type="file"]')[i]
    photo_field.send_keys(ad.photos[i])
```

This will create a random permutation of values from 1 to `ad.photo_counter() - 1`. k is equal to `ad.photo_counter() - 1` since you are starting from index 1 else you would omit the -1. This random permutation will then be looped over using your for loop to generate a random sequence of indices to pick photos with without repeats.

Hope this helps!